# Formatting changes

Tags: formatting, listings

I want some text to appear as below

[image]

I am not getting the exact output. The code I have written is as follows (Please pardon me for lack of knowledge of Latex)

```
\hspace{2mm}  A simple paragraph of Verilog code is below in verbatim.\\
\begin{flushleft}

Always@(posedge LRCK)

\end{flushleft}

\hspace{5mm} Begin\\

\hspace{6mm} Counter=Counter+1\\

\hspace{6mm} If (Counter == 40)\\

\hspace{5mm}Begin\\

\hspace{6mm} Counter = 0\\

\hspace{5mm} $Phase\_control\_word = Phase\_Control\_word + 1 $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the `listings` package which supports `Verilog` language:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={Verilog},tabsize=12,caption={A simple paragraph of Verilog code is below in verbatim}]
  Always@(posedge LRCK)
  Begin
      Counter=Counter+1
      If ( Counter == 40)
         Begin
         Counter = 0
         Phase_control_word = Phase_Control_word + 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another example with `tcolorbox` and its listings features:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing options={language={Verilog},tabsize=12}, title={A simple paragraph of Verilog code is below in verbatim},listing only,colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black}
  Always@(posedge LRCK)
  Begin
      Counter=Counter+1
      If ( Counter == 40)
         Begin
         Counter = 0
         Phase_control_word = Phase_Control_word + 1
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know it was called verilog language... Thank you sir...

Comment: @ShraySharan: It's mentioned in your post aboved, the first line of your screen shot ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the Listing 1: which is in the first line from the output?

Comment: @ShraySharan: Replace `caption=` with `title=`

Comment: Okay got it.. Also can you please tell me why is the result bold even though we didnt use any \bf command?

Comment: That's feature of `listings`. Certain keywords are displayed in bold font. I don't know Verilog, so I can't say whether the right words are highlighted as keywords, but I assume, it's correct

Comment: You don't have to call me Sir:D My name is Christian, that's completely sufficient :D